# ObjectMapper fails with root element

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json, objectmapper

I'm facing an issue that I don't know exactly how to solve.

When I try to map this JSON to User object it fails:

SwiftyJSON at "2.3.3"

JSON:

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "gender":"male",
         "name":{  
            "title":"mr",
            "first":"donald",
            "last":"boor"
         },
         "location":{  
            "street":"1781 vredenburg",
            "city":"het bildt",
            "state":"noord-brabant",
            "postcode":30431
         },
         "email":"donald.boor@example.com",
         "login":{  
            "username":"greenpeacock269",
            "password":"lambda",
            "salt":"2uqekB9c",
            "md5":"4fd97ba849fc6d1abb23134cd554dba8",
            "sha1":"d5adf8eadc9c8b33422ccbc8087333e6dec6f83e",
            "sha256":"2e4b3344d72dc6937fee422149146cb83b6397530e6afdb12daad165abe2b3d9"
         },
         "dob":"1986-12-25 21:32:21",
         "registered":"2016-02-25 06:58:50",
         "phone":"(365)-252-9092",
         "cell":"(962)-625-3483",
         "id":{  
            "name":"BSN",
            "value":"59041461"
         },
         "picture":{  
            "large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/15.jpg",
            "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/15.jpg",
            "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/15.jpg"
         },
         "nat":"NL"
      }
   ],
   "info":{  
      "seed":"806e92dbf96026d0",
      "results":1,
      "page":1,
      "version":"1.1"
   }
}
```

I want to map to my user class:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class User: NSObject, Mappable {
    var gender: String?
    var title: String?
    var first: String?
    var last: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        gender      <- map["gender"]
        title       <- map["name.title"]
        first       <- map["name.first"]
        last        <- map["name.last"]
    }
}

let user = Mapper<User>().mapArray(jsonData) //Doesn't work getting nil
let userList :Array<User> = Mapper<User>().mapArray(jsonData)! //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

RESPONSE CODE:

```
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            do {
                //let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                let jsonResult = JSON(data: data!)
                let dict = jsonResult["results"].dictionaryValue
                let userList :Array<User> = Mapper<User>().mapArray(dict)!
                print(userList)


            } catch {}
        }
```

Comment: can you add the portion of the code where your are getting response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided the code where you are receiving the response, I have tested using test case with the response being put into `test.json` file.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        do {
            let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            let userList :Array<TestUser> = Mapper<TestUser>().mapArray(jsonResult.objectForKey("results"))!
            print(userList)


        } catch {}
    } catch {}
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have implemented `SwiftyJSON` syntax, try the following line of code:

```
let userList :Array<TestUser> = Mapper<TestUser>().mapArray(jsonResult["results"].arrayObject)!
print(userList)
```

Change Model Class to:

```
class TestUser: NSObject, Mappable {
    var gender: String?
    var title: String?
    var first: String?
    var last: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        gender      <- map["gender"]
        title       <- map["name.title"]
        first       <- map["name.first"]
        last        <- map["name.last"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Mr. Hub your code works! but the problem is that i'm getting the response and getting it with SwiftlyJSON, I doesn't work I' will update the code

Comment: I have updated just now I want to use SwifyJSON + ObjectMapper

Comment: When I try to make the mapping Now I get a compile error: 
Cannot invoke 'mapArray' with an argument list of type '([String : JSON])'

I dont know how to parse from SwiftyJSON to your jsonResult.objectForKey("results")

Comment: Sorry but at compile time gives me this error : Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'arrayObjec‌​t'

Comment: Updated code and compile error now says this:  Cannot invoke 'mapArray' with an argument list of type '([String : JSON])'

Comment: Use `arrayObject` instead of `dictionaryValue`, it should work, try once again.

Comment: Happy Coding mate!